# Kivy eventloop misses changes of StringProperty

Tags: python, debugging, kivy, event-loop

I have an app which asks a series of 8 math questions to the user. The user has a keypad with which he can manipulate a label. This label `answer_text` holds the answer, the user wants to submit. Since I had issues, there are two "mechanisms" which allow the checking of this answer (if it is true, the next qestion should pop up, if it is false, nothing should happen). Consider the following code, where I suppress everything unrelated to this problem.

```
from functools import partial

class KeyPad():

    on_key_pad_pressed(self, btn, text):
        cs = App.get_running_app().root.ids.calculation_screen
        if text.isdigit():
            answer_text.text += text
            cs.current_answer = answer_text.text
        elif text == 'clear':
            answer_text.text = ''
        elif text == 'submit':
            cs.on_current_answer(self, btn, text)
        elif text == 'joker'
            Clock.schedule_once(partial(cs.on_current_answer(btn, MathBackEnd().get_true_answer()), 1)

class CalculationScreen(Screen):
    current_answer = StringProperty('')
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def on_current_answer(self, btn, text):
        true_answer = MathBackEnd().get_true_answer()
        if text == true_answer:
             Logger.info('CS: Cool! You got it')
        else:
             Logger.info('CS: Please try again.')
```

So there are at least 3 different ways in Kivy to achieve the wiring between the KeyPad (holds the information about the given answer) and the CalculationScreen (assess given answers). Note that the approach in the first if-case (`cs.current_answer = answer_text.text`) does work, because current_answer is a StringProperty. Therefore, when it changes, its callback `on_current_answer` will get called.

The submit button and the joker button both work fine. If you click 'submit' your answer gets checked. If you click 'joker' the correct answer gets checked with a one second penalty for pressing 'joker'. However answers should get checked automatically (first if-case in "on_key_pad_pressed") and this works except for one case: if the current true answer is the same as the former true answer. Suppose the first question is "3+4", you enter 7 and the game automatically checks your answer. It is true, so you get the next question "1+6". You enter 7... nothing happens. You click 'clear' to clear the answer_text label and press 7 again... nothing happens. You click 'submit'. The answer gets checked and you get the next question.

So, which of these 3 approaches is superior/inferior? Should I always use schedule_once (seems to be very robust)? Do you see why I get this buggy behavior in the first if case, if two successive (true) answers are equal? During calculation, the eventloop gets congested by a timer (timing the response of the user), which updates every tenth of a second. May this congestion lead to this weird behavior?

Any help is much appreciated!

Comment: provide a [mcve]

Comment: I am not sure i fully understand the problem, but if it is about expecting the event to be dispatched even if the value is equal to the previous one, then you should know that this is the way Properties work in Kivy, you can force it by passing [force_dispatch=True](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.properties.html?highlight=stringproperty#kivy.properties.Property), but now that you know how it works, take it in mind and write your logic accordingly.

Comment: @fins Of course! Only if the property changes, the 'Property has changed'-event is fired. And only then the callback gets executed. Thank you very much for the clarification. I think I will switch to schedule_once in all cases, to have it consistent.